# Map and Scan ignore HoldFirst

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, function-construction, attributes

I am trying to write a simple function that takes a list of data and outputs it to a file. I'd like the name of the file to be the same as the variable that holds the list. It seems that giving a function the attribute HoldFirst solves this problem. For example:

```
a = 1;

ClearAll[printName];
SetAttributes[printName, HoldFirst];
printName[var_] := ToString@Unevaluated@var
```

When called, this returns

```
In: printName@a
Out: "a"
```

as expected.

However, things get murkier when I try to Map this function over a list. For example:

```
In: a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;

    l1 = {a, b, c};

    printName /@ l1

Out: {"1", "2", "3"}
```

For some reason Map seems to ignore the attribute HoldFirst. Is there a reason for this? The closest I see in the documentation to an answer is this:

"Map always effectively constructs a complete new expression and then evaluates it."

But, I don't think this is the problem, because I see similar behaviour with Scan.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You have to think about, what happens when you evaluate the line `l1={a,b,c}`. At this point, all your variables on the right side are evaluated and `l1` contains only the data.

The solution is simple: use `Hold` instead of `List`

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;

l1 = Hold[a, b, c];

ReleaseHold[{printName /@ l1}]
```

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks for the help!